# In aircraft air conditioning systems what are the differences between the air cycle machine system and the displacement blower type system?

Tags: aircraft-systems, air-conditioning

I have seen reference to both these different air conditioning systems but can't understand what the key differences are and where each system would likely be found.. I.e is one system preferable over another system on a particular aircraft type?